# Sorting numbers array issue

Tags: c#, sorting

Yesterday at work I set out to figure out how to sort numbers without using the library method `Array.Sort`. I worked on and off when time permitted and finally was able to come up with a basic working algorithm at the end of today. It might be rather stupid and the slowest way, but I am content that I have a working code.

But there is something wrong or missing in the logic, that is causing the output to hang before printing the line: `Numbers Sorted. (12/17/2011 2:11:42 AM)`

This delay is directly proportionate to the number of elements in the array. To be specific, the output just hangs at the position where I put the tilde in the results section below. **The content after tilde is getting printed after that noticeable delay.**

Here is the code that does the sort:

```
while(pass != unsortedNumLen)
{
    for(int i=0,j=1; i < unsortedNumLen-1 && j < unsortedNumLen; i++,j++)
    {
        if (unsorted[i] > unsorted[j])
        {
            pass = 0;
            swaps++;
            Console.Write("Swapping {0} and {1}:\t", unsorted[i], unsorted[j]);
            tmp = unsorted[i];
            unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
            unsorted[j] = tmp;
            printArray(unsorted);
        }

        else pass++;
    }
}
```

The results:

```
Numbers unsorted. (12/17/2011 2:11:19 AM)

4 3 2 1
Swapping 4 and 3:       3 4 2 1
Swapping 4 and 2:       3 2 4 1
Swapping 4 and 1:       3 2 1 4
Swapping 3 and 2:       2 3 1 4
Swapping 3 and 1:       2 1 3 4
Swapping 2 and 1:       1 2 3 4
~
Numbers sorted. (12/17/2011 2:11:42 AM)

1 2 3 4
Number of swaps: 6
```

Can you help identify the issue with my attempt?

[Link to full code](http://pastebin.com/F3yM75VQ)
This is not homework, just me working out.

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you just using `Array.Sort()`?  Or LINQ `OrderBy()`?

Comment: You have "discovered" bubble sort. There are *much* better ways: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: I am aware of both `Array.Sort()` and `LINQ OrderBy()`. I am trying this out to exercise my mind. Nothing serious. I would not use this in any serious project.

Comment: @dlev: I see. I vaguely remember an algorithm from my college days and tried to materialize it. Thanks for letting me know which sort it is in particular

Comment: @KishorNanda No problem. If you follow the link, you'll see that your implementation differs slightly from the standard version, which is why yours is *even slower* than it otherwise could be. The basic difference is that typically, if over the course of a single run through the list no swaps are made, that is proof that the list is now sorted, so no more passes are required.

Comment: On a side note, you may not see those `Write()` right when they occur, if you want to make sure you get the `Write()` immediately, you can flush the output after the write:  `Console.Out.Flush();`

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: This seems interesting, but I think I have not fully grasped yet what you are trying to say. It would be of great help if you could point to me an example or a slightly elaborated explanation. Hope this isn't asking for too much.

Comment: I just meant that if you have a program, and you are printing intermediate state using `Console.Write()`, the `Console.Out` is buffered.  Thus when you call `Write()` it puts data into the buffer.  Once the buffer is full, or a call to `Console.Read()`, etc is called, it will flush that buffer to the screen.  Thus if you have something like: `Operations(); Console.Write("1"); Operations(); Console.Write("2"); Operations(); Console.Write("3");` and `Operations()` takes a long time, it's possible you'll see a long "hang" and then 1, 2, 3 pop up at the end.  So just be wary of timing of output.

Comment: James: That was a great explanation. Thanks for taking time to put the idea across to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a hint to help you work through it and learn, so I am not posting a complete solution.

Change your `else` block to the below and see if it puts you on the right track.

```
else {

    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to do for {0} and {1}", unsorted[i], unsorted[j]);
    pass++;
}
```

Comment: I added the print statement in the else clause like you have said. It printed an infinite number of prints, which is what is causing the delay. Thanks

Comment: @Kishor, it is not infinite if it eventually exits, and your original posted output proves that it does. The extra writes will slow things down even further, but now you should be seeing that you're continuing to run through the loop even though there is no more work to be done. See Andrei's answer for a detailed explanation of why it takes so long for `pass` to equal `unsortedNumLength`.

Comment: Again I'm trying to not give away the answer because I get a feeling you want to practice a thought process, which is a fantastic and rare thing these days.

Comment: David: I understand that the writes will slow the whole thing down. I rely on visual output more to keep track of my progress to see what exactly is happening, and as you've hit the nail on the head, I have completely ignored what was happening in the `else` block. Thank you for showing me the way. Your answer suited me very well and also changed the way I think. Thank you again for your kind words.

Comment: @Kishor Glad to help. Stick with it and hold on to your dedication to thinking / learning!

Comment: @Kishor Also, if I can recommend a book, it has a lot of great advice for determining and correcting the root cause of a problem http://www.amazon.com/Debug-Repair-Prevent-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/193435628X

Comment: @DavidRuttka "it is not infinite if it eventually exits" well yes but it doesn't always exit. It depends on the number of elements. For example if the number of elements is 5 it won't ever exit. This is because  `while(pass != unsortedNumLen)` isn't evaluated after every increment of `pass`. 7 won't either. It may be that odd values the number of elements do this. This also explains why different numbers of elements can take longer. For example when the number of elements is 6 it takes 5 iterations of overflows to get `pass == unsortedNumLen`

Comment: @David: The book seems great and I am sold. I will need to buy it next month, though. Thanks once again. You have been of fantastic help today.

Comment: @ConradFrix You are correct that the loop will never exit for certain array lengths and thank you for clarifying. Kishor and I were discussing the results of his sample of 4, 3, 2, 1 which we see does exit. My point was that adding a Console.WriteLine is not going to change the mathematics of the algorithm (provided the arguments introduce no side effects), so we should not suddenly think that the loop has become infinite when it was not before.

Answer (score 6):

Change the condition in your while to this:

```
while (pass < unsortedNumLen)
```

Logically `pass` **never** equals `unsortedNumLen` so your `while` won't terminate.

`pass` does eventually equal `unsortedNumLen` when it goes over the max value of an `int` and loops around to it.

In order to see what's happening yourself while it's in the hung state, just hit the pause button in Visual Studio and hover your mouse over `pass` to see that it contains a huge value.

You could also set a breakpoint on the `while` line and add a watch for `pass`. That would show you that the first time the list is sorted, `pass` equals 5.

Comment: *EDIT*: My bad, I misunderstood your answer (and maybe the downvoter did too?) In any case, I think your answer could be made clearer (since obviously `pass` does take on the correct value at *some* point) but it is, in general, correct. Consider changing "**never**" to "will take a long to be", since the whole point is that `pass` will continually wrap around until you get lucky and it ends up at `unsortedNumLen`.

Comment: pass is reset to 0 everytime the for loop is executed. Once the array is completely sorted the else increments pass from 0 until pass equals unsortedNumLen so whilst your solution above may work. The explanation of the current code behaviour is incorrect.

Comment: @loudsight No it most certainly is not set to zero every time the for loop is executed. If the numbers are already in order, the if block is never executed, only the else.

Comment: Are any of the rest of you actually executing the OP's code or are y'all just guessing?

Comment: @Dennis I executed it in LINQPad, upvoted you, and added my own answer as a "teach a man to fish" alternative.

Comment: If the array is already sorted then there's no need for a reset to zero to occur since the variable is initialized to zero anyway. So the else just increments pass until pass == unsortedNumLen.

Comment: `pass` exceeds `unsortedNumLen` well before it equals it. :)

Comment: As an aside you if add `checked{}` around the `pass++` 'System.OverflowException' will occur. (it'll also be a bit slower)

Comment: @David Ruttka pass is initialized to 0, how can it ever exceed unsortedNumLen. Please post a number sequence which demonstrates pass exceeding unsortedNumLen. Thanks :-)

Comment: @loudsight 4321. Compare 4 > 3, pass=0. 4 > 2, pass = 0. 4 > 1, pass = 0. While loop continues as 0 != 4. 3214. Compare 3 > 2 (p=0), 3 > 1 (p=0), 3 < 4 so pass++ = 1. While continues as 1 != 4) 2134. 2 > 1 (p=0), 2 < 3 (p++), 3 < 4 (p++). While continues as 2 != 4. 1234. 1 < 2 (p++ = 3), 2 < 3 (p++ = 4), 3 < 4 (p++ = 5). While loop continues as 5 != 4. 1234. See above, while continues as 8 != 4. And on and on.

Comment: @DennisPalmer: I really like your answer too. I am sorry that I have not been able to accept your answer. This was because I was not really looking for _the_ solution, but the _why_ of it. Since this will help me in the future. But I should mention that I really got stimulated by the discussion your answer had prompted. Thanks.

Comment: @KishorNanda that makes sense. Glad you're here and learning the why behind what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix:

```
while(pass < unsortedNumLen)
```

And here is why the delay occurred.

After the end of the `for` loop in which the array was eventually sorted, `pass` contains at most `unsortedNumLen - 2` (if the last change was between first and second members). But it does not equal the `unsorted` array length, so another iteration of `while` and inner `for` starts. Since the array is sorted `unsorted[i] > unsorted[j]` is always false, so pass always gets incremented - exactly the number of times `j` got incremented, and that is the `unsortedNumLen - 1`. Which is not equal to `unsortedNumLen`, and so another iteration of `while` begins. Nothing essentially changed, and after this iteration `pass` contains `2 * (unsortedNumLen - 1)`, which is still not equal to `unsortedNumLen`. And so on.

When pass reaches value `int.MaxValue`, it the overflow happens, and next value the variable `pass` will get is `int.MinValue`. And the process goes on, until `pass` finally gets the value `unsortedNumLen` at the moment the `while` condition is checked. If you are particularly unlucky, this might never happen at all.

P.S. You might want to check out this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: `pass` actually equals `unsortedNumLen + 1` when the list is correctly sorted.

Comment: Actually no, it equals 0. This version of bubble sort "bubbles down", sort to say, i.e. most likely the latest change will take place between first and second elements of the array. At this moment pass equals 0. However at the **end of the `for` loop** in which the array was sorted, pass equals `unsortedNumLen - 2`. But I see the point - will update the answer, thanks.

Comment: The name comes from the values "bubbling" up, rather than the swap points sinking down after each high value is in place. It has also been called "sinking" sort for that reason (and people thought it should have a negative sounding name rather than a happy one), but that name is disputed since it's also used for insertion sorts.

Comment: @Andrei Right. I was looking at it from the perspective of the `while` condition. It does increment by `unsortedNumLen - 1` in successive iterations.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a characteristic of the algorithm you're using to sort. Once it's completed sorting the elements it has no way of knowing the sort is complete, so it does one final pass checking every element again. You can fix this by adding `--unsortedNumLen;` at the end of your for loop as follows:

```
for(int i=0,j=1; i < unsortedNumLen-1 && j < unsortedNumLen; i++,j++)
{
/// existing sorting code
}
--unsortedNumLen;
```

Reason? Because you algorithm is bubbling the biggest value to the end of the array, there is no need to check this element again since it's already been determined to be larger the all other elements.